# Using pb-diagram package

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-cd

I have difficulty in the use of pb-diagram package. I want to be like the output below. Please heip me! Thank you very much!

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: What sort of difficulty do you have? There's also `tikz-cd` for commutative diagrams. Could you post a Minimum Working Example (MWE) of what you have tried so far? A MWE is a compilable document that starts with `\documentclass` shows some relevant code of what you have tried so far and ends with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

A few minutes with `tikz-cd`; much better quality than with `pb-diagram` and much easier syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\id}{\mathit{id}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
& A\otimes A \arrow[dd,"m"] \\
k\otimes A \arrow[ur,"u\otimes\id"] \arrow[dr,"s"] &&
  A\otimes k \arrow[ul,swap,"\id\otimes u"] \arrow [dl,swap,"s"] \\
& A
\end{tikzcd}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=4em,row sep=3em]
\mathbb{K}\otimes C &
  C\otimes C \arrow[l,swap,"\varepsilon_C\otimes\mathbf{1}_C"]
             \arrow[r,"\mathbf{1}_C\otimes\varepsilon_C"] &
  C\otimes\mathbb{K} \\
& C \arrow[ul,swap,"\sim"]
    \arrow[u,"\Delta_C" description]
    \arrow[ur,"\sim"]
\end{tikzcd}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3em,row sep=3em]
C\otimes C\otimes C & C\otimes C \arrow[l,swap,"\Delta\otimes\id"] \\
C\otimes C \arrow[u,"\id\otimes\Delta"] &
  C \arrow[l,"\Delta"] \arrow[u,swap,"\Delta"]
\end{tikzcd}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzcd}
& C\otimes C \arrow[dl,swap,"\varepsilon\otimes\id"]
             \arrow[dr,"\id\otimes\varepsilon"] \\
k\otimes C && C\otimes k \\
& C \arrow[ul,"{-}\otimes 1"]
    \arrow[uu,"\Delta"]
    \arrow[ur,swap,"1\otimes{-}"]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @tranhoang10 If this answer is enough for you, please accept it in order to close this post. This will give egreg some reputation points as kind of 'thank you' or reward. If this answer is not what you have been looking for, please update your question!